# UITableView when changing orientation to landscape cell hight extreme high

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, storyboard

I have a UIView with a NavigationController and a tableView. The table has 1 prototype cell and contains some labels. All "designed" with the storyboard and all constraints are set automatically. So I did with 10 UIViews (for iPhone) in my app, 9 of them displaying correct in portrait- and landscape-mode. One is ok for Portrait-mode, when turning to landscape there is a space about 300px between the cell witch has content for one line and the cell which has content for 20 or 30 lines. And the same space is at the end of that cell. I tried several other constraints, also manual done. I tried other x/y/width/height - settings for the labels without success. The code for the cell-height is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!self.cellNews) {
        self.cellNews = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellNews"];
    }

    theAktuellList = [app.aktuellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *currentLanguage =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents/sprache.txt"]
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    if ([currentLanguage isEqual:@"de"])
    {
        self.cellNews.Titel.text = theAktuellList.TitelD;
        self.cellNews.Datum.text = theAktuellList.DatumD;
        self.cellNews.Nachricht.text = theAktuellList.NachrichtD;
        self.cellNews.Wichtig.text = theAktuellList.WichtigD;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([currentLanguage isEqual:@"fr"])
        {
            self.cellNews.Titel.text = theAktuellList.TitelF;
            self.cellNews.Datum.text = theAktuellList.DatumF;
            self.cellNews.Nachricht.text = theAktuellList.NachrichtF;
            self.cellNews.Wichtig.text = theAktuellList.WichtigF;

        }
        else
        {
            self.cellNews.Titel.text = theAktuellList.TitelE;
            self.cellNews.Datum.text = theAktuellList.DatumE;
            self.cellNews.Nachricht.text = theAktuellList.NachrichtE;
            self.cellNews.Wichtig.text = theAktuellList.WichtigE;

        }
    }

    [self.cellNews layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [self.cellNews.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return height;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 40;
}
```

[image: portrait mode]

[image: landscape mode]

The app is a universal-app. This UIView with the tableView inside and the same content works without any issues on the Pad. Where is my fault or what can I change or try to solve that problem?

EDIT due to Answer of Raj:

Hi Raj, thanks for the link. I went through and found nothing. But I do it again tomorrow. Maybe I didn't talk about the cell and its labels. I have 1 prototype-cell with a height of 45. Inside I have 4 labels with each 25 hight and 10 top and 10 bottom constraint. "Title" has 20 left & right, "Date" has 30 left and 20 right, "Message" has 30 left and 20 right and "Wichtig" has 20 left and right. They are all placed one over the other, because in each cell only one label is used. That means the first cell contains only the Titel, the second cell the Date, the third cell the Message and so on. All constraints of each label are blue and as long as I have only one line of text in the label the cell is built correct. With every additional text line the "top- and bottom-padding" is growing. But the constraint is set to a fixed value.

EDIT 14.08.2014:

I went through the tutorials without any positiv changes. The labelheight is "calculated depending on the labelwidth in portrait orientation. When rotating to landscape, the label has exact the same height as in portrait orientation but the width has grown to nearly twice. The result is a less real textheight which is centered horizontal in the label.

I added a, I think it is more a dirty trick than a proper solution, a returning of height depending the label with long content is used:

```
CGFloat height = [self.cellNews.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

if ([self isLandscapeOrientation]) {

    if (theAktuellList.NachrichtD == nil) {

        return height + 1;

    } else {

        return  height/1.5;

    }

} else {

    return height + 1;

}
```

This works "optically" fine, I get no hint or error but there must be better ways of solving that issue. Every help in which direction to learn/think or searching would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below mentioned tutorial which explain Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout using which you will get an intended output

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout